# How can i subtract two columns in PowerQuery Pivot tables?

Tags: excel, powerbi, pivot, powerquery, powerpivot

I have created a Pivot table based on PowerQuery Datamodel. Under Normal Pivot table, i used to see calculated field where i was able to subtract or add two columns. But i see the option is greyed out in Datamodel Pivots.

Answer (score 0):

In Power Pivot you don't use the legacy "calculated field". Use measures instead.
Instead of accepting the implicit measures that Power Pivot will automatically create for numeric fields when dragged into the Values area of a pivot table, create your own measures in the Data Model window. You can refer to measures in other measure calculations.

That is the Power in Power Pivot.

There are lots of resources for learning about Power Pivot, DAX, measures and the Data Model just a web search away from your fingertips.